# Access violation while using std::function assigned to a member function using std::bind()

Tags: c++

I am making a game engine. I implemented an event system such that my window takes a `WindowData` struct which has information about creating a window. It has a field named `eventCallback` which is a placeholder for a callback function which my window will call when an event occurs.

But, when I am trying to assign my placeholder to my callback function in my client code, I am getting an access violation.

The placeholder is `std::function`, and I am using `std::bind()`.

This is my client code:

```cpp
#include "JetByte.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class App : public JetByte::Application
{
public:
    App();

    void OnInit() override;
    void OnUpdate() override;
    void OnDestroy() override;
    bool EventCallback(JetByte::Event& e);

    ~App();

private:
    bool runningFlag;
    std::shared_ptr<JetByte::Window> window;
    std::shared_ptr<JetByte::GraphicsContext> context;
};

App::App()
{
}

void App::OnInit()
{
    try
    {
        runningFlag = true;
        JetByte::WindowData data;
        data.title = "My window";
        data.eventCallback = std::bind(&App::EventCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        window = JetByte::Window::create({ "My Window" });
        context = JetByte::GraphicsContext::Create(window);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void App::OnUpdate()
{
    while (runningFlag)
    {
        context->Swap();
        window->Update();
    }
}

void App::OnDestroy()
{
    JetByte::EventDispatcher::Stop();
    context.reset();
    window.reset();
}

bool App::EventCallback(JetByte::Event& e)
{
    if (e.GetEventType() == JetByte::EventType::WindowClose)
    {
        std::cout << "window closed" << std::endl;
        runningFlag = false;
    }
    return true;
}

App::~App()
{
}

JetByte::Application* JetByte::ClientApplicationPortal() {
    return new App();
}
```

And this is my `WindowData` struct:

```cpp
struct WindowData {
    const char* title = "JetByte Application";
    int width = 500;
    int height = 500;
    bool vsync = true;
    std::function<bool(Event&)> eventCallback;
};
```

Comment: I think that by the time your event handler gets called the local variable JetByte::WindowData data; in  OnInit has gone out of scope and no longer exist.
Have a look at lambdas and captures so you can keep data alive until its needed : https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/. Lambdas IMO also have a nicer syntax then std::bind. Another option is to pass a copy of WindowData struct as parameter to the event handler.

Comment: Where exactly is the AV occurring? Where is `App::OnInit()` being called? It creates a **local variable** `data` that you are assigning your `eventCallback` to, but then you don't actually use `data` for *anything*, so it just sits there until it goes out of scope when `OnInit()` exits. Where is the code that is trying to call the `eventCallback` when an event happens? How does it know which `eventCallback` to call, if you aren't passing the `eventCallback` around to begin with?

Comment: thanks, everybody I finally solved my problem. the problem was the same as you all mentioned my window data was going out of scope till the time my event system use it. I solved it by making that function placeholder as a member of the window class.
thanks, ​everyone once again.